# How can i run first ng-click and then ui-sref

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I tried to do run first ng-clik and after waiting 1 second tried to load the form page .. if i try like this bellow code sometimes the ng-click works maybe sometimes ui-sref .. i use timeOut but didn't change anything.

```
 <ul class="list-unstyled components" > 
     <li ng-repeat-start="item in Menus">
         <a ng-click="GetFormByMenu(item)" ui-sref="form"  >{{item.DetailName}}</a>
     </li>
     <li  ng-repeat-end></li>
 </ul>
```

Below is the JavaScript code:

```
    app.controller('myController', function ($scope, Services, BilesenServices) 
    {
       $scope.GetFormByMenu = function (Model) {

        $scope.text = '1';
        BilesenServices.GetBilesenByMenuId(Model.Id).then(function (response) {
            $scope.startLabel = response.data.startLabel;
            $scope.endLabel = response.data.endLable;
            $scope.startTimePaker = response.data.startDateTimePaker;
            $scope.endTimePaker = response.data.endDateTimePaker;
            $scope.textBox = response.data.TextBox;
            $scope.musteriLabel = response.data.cNolabel;
            console.log(response.data.startLabel);
            // alert("Herer");

            }, function (error) {
                alert("Error" + error);
            });
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a state change (`ui-sref`) from the controller.

In your case, you can change the code to this:

```js
app.controller('myController', function($scope, $state, Services, BilesenServices) {
  $scope.GetFormByMenu = function(Model) {

    $scope.text = '1';
    BilesenServices.GetBilesenByMenuId(Model.Id).then(function(response) {
      $scope.startLabel = response.data.startLabel;
      $scope.endLabel = response.data.endLable;
      $scope.startTimePaker = response.data.startDateTimePaker;
      $scope.endTimePaker = response.data.endDateTimePaker;
      $scope.textBox = response.data.TextBox;
      $scope.musteriLabel = response.data.cNolabel;
      console.log(response.data.startLabel);
      // alert("Herer");

      $state.go("form"); // you can go to any state you want, even with parameters

    }, function(error) {
      alert("Error" + error);
    });

  }
});
```

```html
<ul class="list-unstyled components">
  <li ng-repeat-start="item in Menus">
    <a ng-click="GetFormByMenu(item)" href="#">{{item.DetailName}}</a>
  </li>
  <li ng-repeat-end>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and remove the `ui-sref` from the html. Don't forget to inject **$state** into your controller if you haven't already.

Documentation: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki

Comment: you can have an empty `href` instead of `href="#"`

Comment: I tried this but but it is not work .. get a error $state is not defined

Comment: @superHero inject it into your controller: `function ($scope, Services, BilesenServices, $state) `

Comment: Updated answer to warn about forgetting to inject $state even though it was already in the code.

Comment: In that case  right click -> "open in a new tab" will not work. Href should be filled properly or on another way you could fill session storage with your states to preset from there in new tab.